# Case-sensitive formula to perform a COUNTIF for number-letter combination of IDs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

We have 15 to 18 symbols long IDs that are a mix of letters and numbers.

On the regular, we need to perform a `COUNTIF()` to determine the exact number of unique IDs.

The issue is that sometimes the only difference between one ID or another is whether the case of one letter is upper or lower.

`COUNTIF()` is not case sensitive and we need to apply a very long formula that converts the IDs to a unique combination of numbers in a separate column and perform the `COUNTIF()` in yet another column.

***It is very important that one of the duplicate IDs is market with 1, as this is key for further processes.***

Is there a more simple, but also an accurate way to do this with a single formula?

The formula in mention:

```
=IFERROR(CODE(MID(AL3,1,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,2,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,3,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,4,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,5,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,6,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,7,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,8,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,9,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,10,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,11,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,12,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,13,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,14,1))&CODE(MID(AL3,15,1))&IFERROR(CODE(MID(AL3,16,1)),""))
```

Some dummy sample IDs:

```
003B999992CcVWS
003B999992GdEDo
003B999992D4afI
003B999992CcVWs
003B999992CcVWZ
003B999992D40gR
003B999992D40gR
003B999992CcVWz
```

Formula's output:

```
484851665757575757506799868783
48485166575757575750711006968111
4848516657575757575068529710273
4848516657575757575067998687115
484851665757575757506799868790
4848516657575757575068524810382
4848516657575757575068524810382
4848516657575757575067998687122
```

The desired output can be seen in the last column on the right:

```
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| # | Account ID      | Formula ID                       | Countif |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 1 | 003B999992CcVWS | 484851665757575757506799868783   | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 2 | 003B999992GdEDo | 48485166575757575750711006968111 | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 3 | 003B999992D4afI | 4848516657575757575068529710273  | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 4 | 003B999992CcVWs | 4848516657575757575067998687115  | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 5 | 003B999992CcVWZ | 484851665757575757506799868790   | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 6 | 003B999992D40gR | 4848516657575757575068524810382  | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 7 | 003B999992D40gR | 4848516657575757575068524810382  | 2       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
| 8 | 003B999992CcVWz | 4848516657575757575067998687122  | 1       |
+---+-----------------+----------------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
={"#", "Account ID", "Formula ID", "Countif";
 ARRAYFORMULA({ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A21:A))), ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({A21:A,
 IFERROR(CODE(MID(A21:A,  1, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  2, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  3, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  4, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  5, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  6, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  7, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  8, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  9, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 10, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 11, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 12, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 13, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 14, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 15, 1))&
 IFERROR(CODE(MID(A21:A, 16, 1)), )),
 IF(LEN(A21:A), MMULT((
 IFERROR(CODE(MID(A21:A,  1, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  2, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  3, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  4, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  5, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  6, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  7, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  8, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  9, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 10, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 11, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 12, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 13, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 14, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 15, 1))&
 IFERROR(CODE(MID(A21:A, 16, 1)), )) = TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(CODE(MID(A21:A,  1, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  2, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  3, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  4, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  5, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  6, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  7, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A,  8, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A,  9, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 10, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 11, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 12, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 13, 1))&
         CODE(MID(A21:A, 14, 1))&CODE(MID(A21:A, 15, 1))&
 IFERROR(CODE(MID(A21:A, 16, 1)), )))) * (ROW(A21:A) >= TRANSPOSE(ROW(A21:A))), 
 SIGN(ROW(A21:A))), IFERROR(1/0))}, COUNTA(A21:A), 3)})}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you for your answer! Your answer provides the correct result. If you could, please, just let me know how can it be adjusted to provide solely the CountIf column, without the rest of the columns, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

How about `MMULT`?

[image]

### Case-sensitive `COUNTIFS`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(
  N(EXACT(A2:A9,TRANSPOSE(A2:A9))),
  ROW(A2:A9)^0
))
```

### Case-sensitive `COUNTIFS` with increment

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(
  {ROW(A2:A9)&A2:A9},
  {
    QUERY(
      {ROW(A2:A9)&A2:A9,A2:A9},
      "select Col1,Col2 order by Col2 label Col1'',Col2''"
    ),
    TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",0,
      IF(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A9)-1)<=QUERY(
        {A2:A9},
        "select count(Col1) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''",
                                  ),
        TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A9)-1),
      )
    ),"|"))
  },
  {3},
))
```

***Updates 2019-09-26 08:01:56***

The final formula is

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(
  (ROW(A2:A17)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A17))) * 
    EXACT(A2:A17,TRANSPOSE(A2:A17))^1,
  ROW(A2:A17)^0
))
```

[Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TpHUfTvA7xBi4TLnWaplGasDumauA3YyMgXjXeQ2cyo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: thank you very much for the effort! However, This is not generating the output that I desire. See, even if there are duplicate IDs I need at least one of them to be counted, as I need the 1 further. the formula that you provide is returning 2 where there are duplicates. My answer must be misleading and it will be corrected. However, I'll upvote your answer for the effort invested, but I can not mark it as a solution.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb, pls share example.

Comment: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)` is the approach that works for us now. Also, I need "1" for the other IDs as well. The 1s are very important, as they are part of further processes.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb this is actually the right direction of how to approach it

Comment: @I.Я.Newb, check again

Comment: @oshliaer , Yes! This works as well. However, I already marked player0's answer as correct. Your effort is much appreciated.

Comment: No need to change your decision. I was wondering if there is an answer to your question. Although the solution @player0 is good.

Comment: @I.Я.Newb I added a new solution